# PHP File Upload Directory

Tags: php, file

I am working on a file upload script. I know that every part of the script is valid, except for the path I am trying to specify.

I am not exactly sure what the path should be relative to. Does it need to be relative to the temporary folder that PHP stores the file in, or relative to the location that my script is running from?

Also, I'm not sure how specific I need to be. The directory where I am trying to upload the file is: `www/mm/uploads`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be relative from the location that the script is running from.

Comment: Okay so my script is located in www/mm/upload.php within that file i should set $target_path = "/uploads/"?